# In Facebook is there a way to add someone to a friend list before they accept your friend request?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-friends

If you go to someone's profile page and add them as a friend, while it's still pending, is there a way to add them to a list? Or do you have to wait for them to actually accept your friend request so that you can, for example, restrict them from viewing certain posts of yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible on the mobile webpage (for example on Safari on the iPhone), but I don't think it is possible on the desktop webpage nor on the App. On the mobile webpage, just tap on the "Requested" button, and choose "Edit friends list".

Answer (score 4):

This seems to keep changing. At the moment I can't see how to do it except for on the mobile web site (not the app) as mentioned by francisaugusto, but the sequence is different.

This works fine from the desktop as long as you use the mobile site (prefix with an "m." instead of "www.").

- Go to https://m.facebook.com/
- Tap the icon, top left, that is of two people's head and shoulders
- To the right of "Friend Requests" there's a drop-down arrow, tap that
- In the menu that opens, tap "View sent requests"

  - Currently that brings you here: https://m.facebook.com/friends/center/requests/outgoing/
- Tap the photo of the person you want to add to lists
- Tap the blue button "Requested"

  - **NOTE! The button is "Cancel Request" on the desktop site**
  - **CLICK IT ANYWAY IT WON't CANCEL IT!**
- Tap "Edit Friend List" and add to the required lists

[image]

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I don't see how this sequence is "different" than the other answer, you just add more to it, in case you're not still on the person's page, which I think francisaugusto was likely assuming.  In both answers, it's tapping on "Requested" (mobile site only [why, Facebook, why?]), and then "Edit Friend List".  Still, this adds two very useful things: the fact that this site can be loaded in desktop (and how to do it), and screenshots to make it easier to see exactly what is meant.  So, thanks!

Comment: I don't think this solution works anymore.  I don't see "Requested" button.  I only see "Cancel" button.  This is truly stupid on Facebook's part!  Now, I cannot add anyone as a friend on Facebook anymore...  This is basic stuff.  How come the highly paid PMs and engineers at Facebook haven't noticed this yet?!

Comment: It still works. It says in my instructions that on the desktop site the button says "Cancel" not "Requested". @doctorram

Comment: @RedYeti I also checked the mobile website and it says "Cancel" only.  I think they've changed the way mobile website works too so that there's no way to do this anymore.  Quite a shame for Facebook!

Comment: `https://m.facebook.com/friends/center/requests/outgoing/` only shows the "Cancel" button now.

Comment: @doctorram I know. It always has done on that URL, as I mention in the answer  Click it and you'll find you have the option.

Comment: @RedYeti I clicked it and it immediately canceled my request without any option to change lists.  :)

Comment: @RedYeti instead of insisting that your solution works, try it yourself and you'll see that it doesn't work anymore.  (I know it used to work at some point.)

Comment: @doctorram Yes, I did try it when you mentioned it the first time. And it did work ‍♂️

Comment: @RedYeti  No, you clearly didn't try it.  I just followed again exactly the steps in your post and still only the "Cancel" button showed up.  Maybe things have changed recently.

Comment: @doctorram  What a truly bizarre thing to say!  Yes, I did try it. It may interest you to know that with very large software services, very often changes are rolled out across clients over a period of many days to weeks. Facebook certainly does this. So you may be seeing a different version of the software to the one I and many others are seeing. 

Honestly... "No, you clearly didn't try it"  Have a nice day  Bye now.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of your main news feed, select 'Friend Lists' (you may need to 'see more' first).

Select the list you want to edit/to which you want to add the individual to whom you sent the friend request.

Upper right corner, click 'Manage List' and select 'Edit List.'

Left side of the window that pops up, change 'on this list' to 'following.'

You can search by the individual's name. Then just click the photo to select them, then click 'finish.'